# Get data from sensor in express server and them in the Front-End

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, polymer

I need your adivce on how to solve an issue :
I have a nodejs modules that allow me to get data from a sensor and I would like to have a UI element that display the data from the sensor (in real time or pseudo-realtime).

Is there a way to setup a data flow from the server to the UI and an "onChange"-like event, update the displaying value ?

PS :
I use Polymer for UI. 
The node_modules is mcp3008.js(and his dependance pi-spi)
First I wanted to Browserify the module in order to use it in my polymer element directly, but it didnt worked.

Have a nice day

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Yes,  usually I always put my whole code, but here since i'm looking for a lead or a hint to do something totally new on my code like "take a look at XXX might be insightful". I judged irrelevant do add it. But i'll add it if you think it could help

Comment: Oh I just remembered, I'm at work I dont have the code in hand :(

Comment: I'm sure you can post a MCVE when you get access to it (even if your question is closed in the meantime, it will get queued for reopening when you edit it).

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems that I will not get any answer here so.
Here is an idea I'll try : 
Write the last data on a txt file from the nodejs server,  and try to if there is a way to read the txt file from the front end components ^^.
Any way have a nice day every one

Comment: Another lead would be using Socket.io :) there is polymer element that handle it.